# What is the worst case time complexity of this rudimentary graph search?

Tags: python, complexity-theory

I was asked the other day to write a basic method which, when given two friends, would return true if they were linked (by that I mean they're friend of a friend of a friend) or false if they're unrelated (no one in either of their friend lists are connected).

After working with this person, here is the basic algorithm we came to:

```
def is_linked(friend_a, friend_b, visited = {}):

  is_found = False
  friends = friend_a.get_friends()

  # You can assume this method is O(1)
  if friends.contains(friend_b):
    return True

  visited[friend_a] = 1
  for friend in friends:

    # Prevents infinite recursion
    # Assume O(1)
    if friend in visited:
      next

    is_found = is_linked(friend, friend_b, visited)
    if is_found:
      last

  del visited[friend_a]
  return is_found
```

**What is the worst-case time complexity of this algorithm?**  We each came up with our own answer and since we couldn't come to an agreement I'm hoping to independently verify here.

Comment: Looks `O(n^2)` to me.

Comment: @AaronMiller - would you mind putting it into an answer w/an explanation?

Comment: What cost do you put on `if friend in visited`?  If `O(1)`, the whole thing is `O(n)`. Otherwise, I think Aaron is right.

Comment: @dlp - assume O(1) for `if friend in visited`.  That being said, could you post reasoning for O(n) as an answer?  Honestly, I'm thinking O(n^2) even with the if statement being O(1) so I'd be interested in seeing why.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. I'm not sure. My graph theory is weak, but this seems like a variation of [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), no? That really puts you at `O(n^2)` as it says there.

Comment: @Dave Answer added; I'm no mathematician so am unable to produce a formal proof with which to substantiate my reasoning, but maybe it's not completely bogus all the same.

Comment: @dlp If Python `in` were O(n), I'd still think O(n^2) for `is_linked`, but they claim O(1) for `in` and I'm willing to believe O(log n), which seems to put the whole thing at O(n log n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to throw my answer out there. I think is covered by the [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) article on Wikipedia which shows that it really is dependent on the number of edges `E` and nodes `N` and has different best and worst case values. Your code with key areas commented

```
def is_linked(friend_a, friend_b, visited = {}): # At worst, will call this N-1 times

    friends = friend_a.get_friends()

    # You can assume this method is O(1)
    if friends.contains(friend_b):
        return True

    visited[friend_a] = 1
    for friend in friends:

        # Prevents infinite recursion
        # Assume O(1)
        if friend in visited:
            next # At worst, this will happen N-2 times

        return is_linked(friend, friend_b, visited)

    del visited[friend_a]
    return False
```

Absolute worst case? `O((N-1)(N-2))` which is really `O(N^2)`. If you can say your graph is sparsely connected, you can get as good as `O(N)` because the `if friend in visited: next` will rarely happen.

Answer (score 1):

If both `if friend in visited` and `friends.contains` are O(1), then the function as a whole must be O(n); if a single call to `is_linked` (assuming no recursion) completes in constant time (as it must if everything it's doing completes in constant time), then the completion time for a call with recursion scales linearly with the number of recursions which occur, i.e., the number of friends which have to be examined to find a link. I'm not equipped to produce a mathematical proof of this, but consider:

```
a[friends] = [c, d, e]
b[friends] = [e, f, g]
[...]
e[friends] = [a, b]
```

In this case, calling `is_linked(a, b)` will result in a total of four calls:

is_linked(a, b) # original call
   is_linked(c, b, {a: 1})
   is_linked(d, b, {a: 1, c: 1})
   is_linked(e, b, {a: 1, c: 1, d: 1}) # True

Similarly:

```
a[friends] = [b, c]
b[friends] = [c, d]
c[friends] = [d, e]
d[friends] = [e]
```

with a call to `is_linked(a, e)` also results in four calls:

```
is_linked(a, e) # original call
is_linked(b, e, {a: 1})
is_linked(c, e, {a: 1, b: 1})
is_linked(d, e, {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}) # True
```

Meanwhile:

```
a[friends] = [b, c, d, e, f, g]
[...]
g[friends] = []
```

with `is_linked(a, g)` results in six calls, &c. The point of all this is to demonstrate, if not to prove, that the time spent in `is_linked` scales linearly with the number of items it has to examine.

I'm not immediately familiar with Python's implementation of dictionary key lookup (`if friend in visited`); a naïve implementation, as a linear search across an array of keys, would have complexity O(n), resulting in the O(n^2) complexity I originally assumed for `is_linked`. But, according to [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys) they've got it down to "average complexity of O(1)". If that's true, then `is_linked` is indeed O(n); if, as I suspect may be the case, in practice it's closer to O(log n), then `is_linked` should be O(n log n), which still isn't all that bad.

**Update**: dlp points out that there's an array traversal (`for friend in friends`) in `is_linked`, as well as a key lookup. That iteration's always going to be O(n), which would make `is_linked` necessarily O(n^2) at least. (Can something be O(n^2 log n)? Any computer scientists in the house? I mean, I'm not one...)

Comment: I was thinking that too, but the `for friend in friends` can grow with `n` as well. That means as you travel through the graph, each recursive call can have an inner loop iterate through up to `n-1` times before it returns. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Oh crap, you're right, that `in` is an array traversal while the other one's a key lookup. Bloody Python.

Comment: The use of `visited` will help prune that loop, but in the worst case (e.g. trivially `a[friends] = [g, h, i, j, k, l, b]; b[friends] = []; is_linked(a, b)`) `n-1` iterations are still required, so, yeah, O(n).

Comment: (And, parenthetically, this is why I like Perl: array traversal is `for(;;)` as in C, or `foreach my $item (@array)`, while key lookup is `defined($hash{'key'})`. More verbose syntax, perhaps, but you don't trip over yourself when you encounter, for example, `in` meaning two completely different things in the space of as many lines of code.)

Comment: @rdp, I agree `in` by itself wouldn't mean an array scan. `for element in iterable` would mean a scan, as in this case where the code is `for friend in friends:`.

Comment: @dlp i removed my comment, the for loop makes my point moot as you noted.